# Why does Argentobaumhauerite have decimals in its chemical formula?

Tags: mineralogy

[Argentobaumhauerite's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentobaumhauerite) lists its chemical formula as $\require{mhchem}\ce{Ag_{1.5}Pb_{22}As_{33.5}S_{72}}$. Is there a reason this chemical formula is not represented as whole-number ratios of each element?

Comment: Well, $\require{mhchem}$ $\ce{Fe_{0.93}O}$ is not written as $\ce{Fe93O100}$ either.

Comment: See these Chemistry SE questions: ["How can there be decimal subscripts in a molecular formula?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/62979/127719),
["What is the meaning of a decimal in a subscript in a chemical formulas?"](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/64260/127719).

Comment: Thanks @DavidBailey, can I infer then that Argentobaumhauerite's elements are non-covalently bonded? Knowing this, can I interpret a different structure?